# Booting problem In Dell Vostro 3480 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, bios, dell-vostro

I purchased a Dell (Vostro 3000 Core i5 8th Gen - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/Linux) VOS 3480) Laptop with Ubuntu (Version 18.04) installed. After 10-15 days of usage, it started showing a booting problem. It can be switched on, but only if the charger cable is connected for some time. Then it'll start. Else it starts and stands idle with an empty screen.

I raised this issue with Dell, and a Dell executive investigated and decided that the problem is because of a corrupted OS. He asked me to change the OS to Windows or reinstall Ubuntu.

Currently, the BIOS is not an updated version(1.4.1)?
Could this be an issue?
Any solution apart from reinstalling OS?

The screen appears like this for an infinite amount of time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try to see if secure boot is disabled. Turn on your laptop and press f2 continuously to enter into BIOS. Then check if secure boot is disabled.
If the problem still persists then reinstall Ubuntu only as it is open-source and free to use. Don't install Windows since installing a licensed version will cost you upwards of Rs 7000.